# session flush automaically in express-session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

In express-session i got problem to maintain persistent session with nodejs.

in logincontroller.js

```
 if(!req.session.authEmail)
 req.session.authEmail = req.body.data.datasendtonode.signInEmailId;
console.log(req.session.authEmail);
```

this show me session value

in 
tokenSignIn.js

```
var useremail=req.session.authEmail;
    console.log(useremail);
```

this show undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have to detail better the flow of your problem and show the configuration params of the session, but if it is a problem of persistence between redirections, in the documentation it is recommended to save the session before redirecting the request.

```html
router.get('/auth', (req, res, next)=>{

    // YOUR  PREVIOUS CODE

    if(!req.session.authEmail){
        req.session.authEmail = req.body.data.datasendtonode.signInEmailId        
    }

    // YOUR NEXT CODE

    req.session.save((err)=>{
        if(!err){
            return res.redirect('/theRouteToRedirect')
        } 
        else { console.log(err) }
    })
})
```

[Session.save(callback)](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsavecallback)

Answer (score 0):

By default express stores session in the memory and the session will be lost everytime you restart the app. If you want your session to persist you'll have to check out something like redis-connect or mongo-connect.

Shows us your auth procedure and current session setup so we can better answer your question.